# handling Single quote in string in JS and Code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, globalization

i have a string in my resource file that i am using in my codebehind and in javascript,but it is throwing error in JS.

Resource file string is **Par des changements de l'espace réservé**

How to use escape character that will work in all three cases

1.JS (eg i am comparing the inner text of TD with that resource value)

2.Code behind (setting the inner text of TD with that resource value )

3.ASPX (setting the text property of label with resource value)

in case of single quotes?

if i use the value in resource file with backward slash escape character,it will print the value in code behind with that slash.
 **Par des changements de l\'espace réservé**

Comment: Have you tried `\'` yet? As in `"...de l\'espace..."` (Though if the string is quoted in double-quotes you shouldn't need to escape the apostrophe at all.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your backend code to dynamically create your front-end JS, you also have your JS use double-quoted strings.

This example is in pseudocode, and might actually work if you wrote it into a PHP file (I know that's not what you're using):

```
var myStringInJS = "<%=myStringFromResourceFile%>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape characters using a back slash (`\`):

```
var a = 'Par des changements de l\'espace réservé';
```

Comment: but if i print this string in aspx.cs,it will print the string as 'Par des changements de l\'espace réservé';..(will print \ in code behind)

Answer (score 0):

This can be very tricky, so what I do is:

1. In the server side code, always use double quotes `"`
2. Javascript always use single quotes `'`
3. In the server side code javascript strings, I always escape the single quote using a `\'`

That stops any messy code from happening.

The value therefore in your resource file would be:

```
Par des changements de l\'espace réservé
```

Resulting in a server side string value of:

```
string javascriptEscapedText = "Par des changements de l\'espace réservé";
```

And javascript string value:

```
var escapedText = 'Par des changements de l\'espace réservé';
```